# Dell C840 hangs on resume from standby

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, power-management, dell-latitude, standby

I have an older laptop - Dell Latitude C840 - with Windows XP Pro SP3. Everything works fine except for standby. It will go into standby but has great difficulty getting back out. On resume, sometimes it will hang altogether or it can be slow as dirt with cpu running at 100%. From the Task Manager, the 'System' process is the one using the cpu.
It is a clean XP install that I did a couple of years ago, not Dell-installed.
Any ideas what it might be?
I came across [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822624) article.

I am not sure if it applies to my laptop. Should I append `/forceresetreg` to my boot.ini file? Currently, it doesn't have this switch. I didn't specifically install this hotfix, but I think it should be part of SP3.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a second HDD fitted?

Comment: @Tog No. I have a DVD-ROM/CD-RW drive and a DVD-ROM modular drive. The only HDD is dual boot with linux, but I don't think it should matter. I haven't done this enough to establish a pattern, as I hate it when I have to do a hard power down, but I think the problem may get worse the longer it stays in sleep, like more then just a few minutes. I have successfully brought it out of sleep when it was only a few minutes. Also a web browser is suspect when I have a bunch of sites loaded in memory. I am not sure. What happens to all that JavaScript and whatnot when it goes to standby?